# C# Newbie - Nested methods yet another System.NullReferenceException-Object error

Tags: c#

For purposes of learning, I've setup a method to call upon another method to display a value I defined via user input.  However, I end up getting a nasty error:

> System.NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Could someone please explain what I'm doing to cause the error; and, make this work without changing the code too much (keeping the nested methods).

**Program.cs**

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parent theParent = new Parent();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Child Name:");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            theParent.Child.Name = input;

            theParent.FirstMethod();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Parent.cs**

```
namespace Test
{
    class Parent
    {
        public Child Child = new Child();   //I changed this line.  It was originally only 'public Child Child'

        public void FirstMethod()
        {
            Child newChild = new Child();
            newChild.SecondMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

**Child.cs**

```
namespace Test
{
    class Child
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public void SecondMethod()
        {
            Parent theParent = new Parent();
            Console.WriteLine(theParent.Child.Name.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Child` is `null`.

First you create a new `Parent`:

```
Parent theParent = new Parent();
```

This has a `public` field `child` (note: use a property, not a public field):

```
public Child Child;
```

As you can see: this is uninstantiated.

Then you use this child:

```
theParent.Child.Name = input;
```

But `child` is `null`! Thus, the `NullReferenceException`.

You have to instante the `child` field:

```
public Child Child = new Child();
```

Or in another place, that's up to you.

Sidenote about the public field: you're breaking encapsulation by providing direct access to an instance member. You should use getters & setters (in C# conveniently provided by a property).

New situation:

```
void Main()
{
    Parent theParent = new Parent();
    string input = "jack";
    theParent.Child.parent = theParent; // ADD THIS
    theParent.Child.Name = input;

    theParent.FirstMethod();
}

class Parent
    {
        public Child Child = new Child();   //I changed this line.  It was originally only 'public Child Child'

        public void FirstMethod()
        {
        //  Child.parent = this; // REMOVE THIS
            Child.SecondMethod();
        }
    }

class Child
{
   public Parent parent;
   private string name;

   public string Name
   {
       get { return name; }
       set { name = value; }
   }

   public void SecondMethod()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(parent.Child.Name);
   }
}
```

Output:

> jack

Comment: Thanks.  When I replaced "public Child Child" with "public Child Child = new Child();" that took care of one error.  However, there is also the same error message complaining about the line "Console.WriteLine(theParent.Child.Name.ToString());" in Child.cs

Comment: @MKANET: try removing the `.ToString()`. `Name` is already a `string` so it shouldn't make a difference. But if `string` is `null`, it will throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: I already tried that.  The string is blank.  It doesnt show the value to theParent.Child.Name (from the user input earlier).

Comment: Can you edit your post with the code that you currently have and the exact error message?

Comment: My exact code is already posted (minus the using lines above).  The only thing different is I replaced public Child Child   with  public Child Child = new Child();

Comment: Okay, I updated the code above with the change in the line.  It should be very easy to reproduce.  These null exception errors are really annoying for a beginner!

Comment: @MKANET: the problem is that you create a new Child and a new Parent inside for no appearant reason. I'll edit my post with something that compiles and works, tell me if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Part of my learning is keeping separate class files (to make it a little more difficult on purpose).  Any chance you could redo so it would work like my original example?

Comment: What do you mean with different class files? You could just post this in different `.cs` files, yes.

Comment: Sorry.  My bad, the code works perfectly in different .cs files.  Thank you so much.  Just out of curiosity, could you please tell me what "Child.parent = this;" does?

Comment: I haven't studdied "this" yet.  Is there any way to do it without using the line  "Child.parent = this"?  So, it's more closer to how I had it?

Comment: @MKANET: it sets the `parent` property in `Child` equal to `this`. `this` is just a referral to the current object you're in. I'll edit my post with a workaround that does the same.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your patience in teach a total newbie.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, I want Child to be an "aggregated class" of Parent (where the Parent class has ownership of that class child), not the other way around. I hope I'm wording this right.

Comment: You're trying to create a bi-directional relationship between `Child` and `Parent`. If you want to have the child know about its parent, you need to have a property to store the parent in. Otherwise they can't know about eachother (unless you add dictionaries in a third class, but that's probably out of the scope of your question).

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  It didn't occur to me that the Child class needs to know about Parent class in order to invoke the Parent class's method.  I really appreciate all your help; and, for going way beyond the scope of a stackoveroverflow answer to help me out.

Comment: No problem, we've all been there. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Reference types (classes) are initialized to `null`. In your `Parent` type, you declare `Child` like this:

```
public Child Child;
```

This makes the `Child` field `null`. You need to initialize it inline.. or set it in a constructor:

```
public Child Child = new Child();
```

...or...

```
public Parent() {
    Child = new Child();
}
```

..or even inline when declaring the `Parent` object:

```
Parent theParent = new Parent() { Child = new Child() };
```

Same for any others like this.

Comment: Thanks.  When I replaced "public Child Child" with "public Child Child = new Child();" that took care of one error.  However, there is also the same error message complaining about the line "Console.WriteLine(theParent.Child.Name.ToString());" in Child.cs

Comment: @MKANET take what you learned in `Parent` and apply it to `Child`. If `Parent.Child` started out null until you set it to a value what do you think is happening to `Child.Name`?